# Why the bandwidth of the system with the minimum-order observer is higher than the full-order observer?

Tags: frequency, frequency-response, control-systems, bandwidth

In Ogata's *Modern Control Engineering* (5th Ed., page 786) it says:

> The bandwidth of the system with the minimum-order observer is higher
>   than that of the system with the full-order observer, provided that
>   the multiple observer poles are placed at the same place for both
>   observers.

Can anyone explain me why this is so?

Answer (score 1):

I think the key of that statement is the sentence

> [...] provided that the multiple observer poles are placed at the same place for both observers.

Suppose that you have a Bode plot, with poles at $\omega_1,\omega_2,...,\omega_n$. If you leave those poles as they are (i.e. you **don't** change their locations) and you *add* more poles to the system, then the bandwidth will decrease.

Why? Well, suppose we add a single pole at $\omega_{n+1}$. In that case, the slope of the magnitude as a function of the frequency will decrease for all the frequencies such that $\omega>\omega_{n+1}$. If the magnitude was increasing, it will increase slower or will become constant  (referring to the asymptotic Bode plot). If it was decreasing, it will decrease faster.

If you add even *more* poles and not just one, then, following the same reasoning, the bandwidth will decrease more abruptly.